# Get a Map of fields from Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve a map field in a document which consists of maps inside it.

***world*** is a JSON map consisting of maps.

I would like to retrieve these maps in flutter in order to parse them to a custom object.

[image]

I tried this:

```
Stream<DocumentSnapshot> provideDocumentFieldStream() {
    return Firestore.instance
        .collection('regular-news')
        .document('us-en')
        .snapshots();
  }


  Future<NewsModel> getWorldNews() async {
    final NewsModel nm = NewsModel();
    List<Articles> list = List<Articles>();
    var articles = await Firestore.instance
        .collection("regular-news")
        .document("us-en")
        .get();
```

I am unable to retrieve the map of maps in the variable articles.

Tried to use a stream like that:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Stream Test',
      body: new StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('regular-news').document('us-en').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return new Text("Loading");
          } else {
            return new Text(snapshot.data.data.toString());
          }
        }),

  );

    controller: scrollController;
  }
```

but when I assign it to a string it says:

The argument type 'Map' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)

Comment: what are u getting here `Stream<DocumentSnapshot> provideDocumentFieldStream() {
    return Firestore.instance
        .collection('regular-news')
        .document('us-en')
        .snapshots();
  }`?

Comment: I was trying to use a stream, but that didn't really work. Because I still need to insert the map into a list. And apparently something is missing.

Comment: how are u using the stream?

Comment: I have edited the original post

Comment: This must be some other part of code, as here you are not assign any Map object. Can you show assignment statements?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to save the maps inside a list of dynamic values:

```
List<Articles> list = List<Articles>();

    var val = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('collection')
        .document('document').get();

        LinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> data = val['fieldvalue'];

        List<dynamic> values = data.values.toList();

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
          list.add(Articles.fromJson(values[i]));

        }
```

Then processing the data in the list afterwards was simpler than dealing with documents snapshots.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Try it it will help even though I can't add recyclerview

```
 private void gettow() {
    dataFire.collection("user").document("user1").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
            if(error != null){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "502", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                // value.getData().get("info")

                Map<String, Object> objects = (Map<String, Object>) value.getData().get("info2");

                String comment = (String) objects.get("comment");
                String tagName = (String) objects.get("tagName");

                User user = new User(comment,tagName);

                user.setComment(comment);
                user.setTagName(tagName);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "=> " + comment + user.getComment(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               
            }

        }
    });

}
```